WSL2 MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev after glxinfo -B
Premise: I am a novice in this topic
I am trying to set up my WSL to test numerical calculations (based on OpenGL) on GPUs.
I have already installed CUDA, nvcc --version, nvidia-smi and glxgears all seem to be working correctly (See here for output).
However, I have the following output after glxinfo -B:
name of display: :0
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
glx: failed to create drisw screen
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Microsoft Corporation (0xffffffff)
    Device: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 24.0.9
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 11996MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10

This is interfering with my application, leading to crashes in test cases.
I tried upgrading to a newer version of MESA using ppa but it led to another error.
Do you have any idea how to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Other informations:
Ubuntu 24.04
PC: Razer Blade-stelth
Graphic card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design
Windows 11

This looks to be related to this wslg issue or this Ubuntu mesa issue

Thank you @Holger for your response.
I have already tried those steps: more importantly, from what I understood export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 tells the compiler to use software acceleration instead of hardware acceleration, reducing the performance of the code. Therefore, in my case at least, I don't think it is what I am looking for.
NONETHELESS, thanks to @popey's comment pointing to this link, I was able to solve the problem by setting export GALLIUM_DRIVER=d3d12.
Now when I run glxinfo -B I get a clean output:
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Microsoft Corporation (0xffffffff)
    Device: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 24.0.9
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 11996MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10

Thanks again for all the help!

I had a similar problem and the following helped me:
sudo apt install mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

It may not be possible to install libgl1-mesa-glx, however it still works with the environment variable set.
